# How to set showing only Username on on-premises GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

Does anyone know how to set **showing only "Username"** instead "Name" with "UserName" on any activities, on on-premises GitLab?

Currently (by default) GitLab showing "Name" on everywhere. I don't like this style:(

[My GitLab Activity Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70CQ8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard on the Twitter that the function to which show either "Username" or "Name" selectively is currently not available on GitLab, and which is asked for a implementation.
Great thanks for the help.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17607